# Entity framework Linq very slow queries

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

i need some help optimizing linq queries in c#. I have a little application, it uses entity framework, and inside is some code like:

```
using (var db = new MyEntities())
{
  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Start: " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
  var myData = from table1 in db.Table1
  join table2 in db.Table2 on table1.Key equals table2.Key
  // more joins from various tables
  where table1.Date > StartDate && table1.Date < EndDate
  select table1;
  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("After myData: " + DateTime.Now.ToString());

  var count = myData.Count();
  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("After Count(): " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
  var list = myData.ToList();
  foreach(var variable in list)
  {
    //do something;
  }
}
return
```

In these tables, there is about 200.000 rows. The thing is, even if Count() returns 0, Count() takes about 10 seconds, and if there are a few thousand rows, then it takes very long time(at least 10 minutes) and then i get error, that variable is null. Is there some kind of techniques or something that would help me to optimize linq queries ?

Comment: I'd start by looking at the SQL generated with the profiler or EF logging (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx). You have indexing on the keys? Move the where cause up before the joins since in only appears to look at the first table. Also, you may not need the joins if you have navigational properties in the models.

Comment: How long does the linq statement need? Maybe the query is lazy loaded and when you count the data is fetched

Answer (score 1):

I would bet that it's not an EF or LINQ issue here. Your database still needs to be constructed with proper indexing.  If you set a breakpoint and check your intellitrace window you will be able to see your actual query being executed. Copy that query into SQL Server Management Studio and see how the query performs. This can give you hints on how to setup indexes to optimize this query.  Any time you join, you open the possibility for slower executing queries. Any WHERE clause that doesn't match your indexes will open the possibility for slower executing queries.

Note: There are thousands of books about the proper way to index your database so please use care when doing this.

Note 2: Rather than DateTime.Now for your timing, use the Stopwatch class. You'll have more consistent results.

```
var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
//do code
sw.Stop();
Debug.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
```

Comment: Well, i got SQL query by using Database.Log = Console.Write, then i executed that query in MS SQL Server on my database, and it executed that query almost instantly. The thing is, when i have code
      var myData = from table1 in db.Table1 ...

Comment: Well, i got SQL query by using Database.Log = Console.Write, then i executed that query in MS SQL Server on my database, and it executed that query almost instantly. The thing is, when i have code "var myData = from table1 in db.Table1 ... select table1;" it is only a SQL statement, not the data itself, but when i do "var list = myData.ToList();" then list is actual data, and even if myData result is empty, it takes like 10 seconds to make that empty query to list, and over a minute, if result has like 10 rows.

Comment: And what would be better / faster - 1 big linq query with 10-20 joins and 10-20 compares in "where" part, or 10-20 smaller queries without joins and with separate "Where()" sentences, like "var myData = from table1 in db.Table1 select table1; myData = myData.Where(<,>,!,...); myData = myData.Where(>,<,!=, >=);......." ?

Comment: @newuser205 I've had to do both scenarios before. Lots of small ones will release database resources quicker as the 1 big query may lock tables. The other thing the slowness could be is just the shear size of the data being transferred. 200,000 rows is a lot of data. When executing the query in SSMS it will stream results. A .ToList() will not be streaming the results. I'd consider using Skip and Take and build a pager. I've found that about 100 results is the most that a single UI element should have without paging. Paging can be dynamic based on scroll position without having page buttons.

Comment: Yes, 200.000 rows in a table is not a small amount, but still, it shouldnt take so long, you can run SQL query with many conditions in ms sql server, and it will be executed in a second, even with a few hundred thousands of rows. I changed that big one sentence with a lot of joins and a lot of conditions to one little sentence and many small conditions, one sentence for one condition, and now it seems to run almost instantly. I suspect that that one big sentence with many joins was making one big ass table with much more than 200.000 rows.